# The language DLL 'VB6FR.DLL' could not be found

Tags: dll, deployment, vb6

I have developed a VB6 application with Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Enterprise Edition SP6.
I have copied the executable file to a computer C where VB6 is not installed.
I have installed on computer C the VB6 SP6 run-time redistribution pack available on this page : http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=24417
The following error message is displayed when I launch my application from computer C : The language DLL 'VB6FR.DLL' could not be found.

Why the VB6 SP6 run-time redistribution pack does not contain VB6FR.DLL ?
What pack contains VB6FR.DLL ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in most cases, you cant just copy VB6 app files to a computer, they have to be installed, components need to be registered and so forth.  but, that file would be part of the 'international package and deployment kit'.  it doesnt seem to be available on MS anymore, so you may need to beg a Frenchman for a copy.

Comment: We deploy this dll (and the german and italian ones) with one of our applications. I can send them to you if you like.

Comment: @Dabblernl How do you deploy VB6FR.DLL ?

Comment: I'll have to look in the installer, the script was written ages ago :-)

Comment: @Plutonix Can I install the IPDK on computer C to deploy VB6FR.DLL on computer C ?

Comment: Had to vote to close because this kind of question is against the rules, but here's where it can be found: http://www.logitheque.com/logiciels/windows/utilitaires/dll/telecharger/vb6frdll_9047.htm

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518024/where-to-get-vb6-localization-support-binaries

Answer (score 0):

You might have a better chance with the English/US version:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24417

But to be clear, you cannot just copy VB6 from one system to another and expect the IDE itself to work fine, which is what I think you might be trying to do.  Your best bet is to find the original CD and re-install it on the new system, or consider switching to VB.NET, which I honestly would personally avoid if it's a big project.