# Where to get VB6 localization support binaries

Tags: localization, vb6

In the document [Support Statement for Visual Basic 6.0 on Windows...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx) it states:

> **Localization Support Binaries**
>
> The following binaries are necessary for supporting Visual Basic 6.0
>   applications running on localized versions of the Windows operating
>   system. They are supported but are not shipped in Windows. These files
>   are required to be shipped with your application setup.

That seems pretty clear in itself.

For instance, `mfc42jpn.dll` is required for Japan, `mfc42ita.dll` for Italy, etc.

However, I cannot find any source of these files from Microsoft. Where can they be sourced?

Note - there are some random DLL download websites which turn up the correct filenames, but I'd far prefer an authoritative source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply [SP6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5721).  According to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/194022), it *covers all English versions of these products, as well as all localized versions*.

---

On the VB6 installation CD those files can be found in the `\OS\SYSTEM` folder.

For the OP's given example of MFC42.dll it includes:

- MFC42.DLL
- MFC42CHS.DLL
- MFC42CHT.DLL
- MFC42DEU.DLL
- MFC42ENU.DLL
- MFC42ESP.DLL
- MFC42FRA.DLL
- MFC42ITA.DLL
- MFC42JPN.DLL
- MFC42KOR.DLL

Comment: Plus one but it might be better to get the latest update to SP6, the *Service Pack 6 Cumulative Update*. To be future-proof, I recommend inking to the [Microsoft VB6 downloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/aa662927) list rather than direct to any specific patch

Comment: The service pack page states, ``"Each service pack detects the files you have installed on your system and installs the appropriate fixes"``. So I'm not sure if that is quite what we need. It sounds like that will install files matching the locale of the PC - but we need to redistribute binaries for multiple locales (include them in our setup).

Comment: I downloaded `VB60SP6-KB2708437-x86-FRA.msi` (French version of SP6) and unpacked it with 7-Zip. It does not contain any of the files that are in the localization support binaries list. For instance, it does have `tabctl32.ocx`, but does not have `tabctfr.dll`.

Comment: @DaveInCaz - I just dug out my installation CD and found those files in the \OS\SYSTEM folder.

Comment: I looked through the SP6 installation CD and it doesn't actually include these itself, although MFC42.dll is included.