# What are VB6 localization support binaries for?

Tags: localization, vb6

In the document [Support Statement for Visual Basic 6.0 on Windows...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx) it states:

> **Localization Support Binaries**
>
> The following binaries *are necessary* for supporting Visual Basic 6.0
>   applications running on localized versions of the Windows operating
>   system. They are supported but are not shipped in Windows. These files
>   *are required* to be shipped with your application setup.

For instance, `mfc42jpn.dll` is required for Japan, `mfc42ita.dll` for Italy, etc.

**But what do these localization files actually do?** Why do they need to be included?

We have been shipping software internationally for years without including these files and, AFAIK, no one has had any problems because of it.

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518024/where-to-get-vb6-localization-support-binaries about where to actually get these binaries.

Comment: I don't have time to check but AFAICR they contain translations. So if you do ship the Japanese file, your Japanese users will see Japanese for some text from the VB6 runtime. For instance if you implicitly convert `True` to a string, it will be the Japanese for "True", not the English. If you do not ship the Japanese file (and if the file is not already installed on the user's PC) it will be the English "True". So it depends on your code whether it makes any difference. In fact it may even expose bugs if you DO ship the files: I've seen this when legacy code builds SQL strings from Booleans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are satellite DLLs that contain string resources in various languages for the OCXs and DLLs they correspond to.  For the most part those are exception description text values, or other text values here and there depending on the control involved.  I suppose they might also contain Help string values as well displayed for example in the IDE's Object Browser at design time.

AFAIK, implicit and old-style conversions (e.g. `Str$()`) of Boolean values always use US English (the *Invariant Locale*) but proper explicit conversion operations (e.g. `CStr()`) will use OLE conversions with the current session locale.  These satellite DLLs are not involved there.  It is also possible to invoke the OLE formatting functions directly, passing specific LCIDs.